# (gdb) gcore gcore warning: Memory read faile

Tags: gdb, coredump

I use gdb on Andorid ,in the Android shell:
./gdb --pid 29083
...
 gcore
warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 8192 bytes at 0x730c5000.
Saved corefile core.29083
(gdb)

I also set ulimit -c 50000 but still the core dump exceeds this limit. When I do ls -l to check file size it is over 300 MB. In this case how should I limit the size of core dump?

How to limit the size of core dump file when generating it using GDB?

Comment: The argument to the `ulimit` shell command is in 1024-byte blocks, so you're actually setting a limit of 50MB. But, what is the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` on your system? If it's a pipe, the coredump limit is ignored by the kernel and it's up to the program being piped to to honor the limit. I don't know about Android, but on my Ubuntu system, it's piped to `apport`, and `apport` apparently has a bug where it multiplies the core limit by another 1024.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `root@mako:/proc/sys/kernel # cat core_pipe_limit
cat core_pipe_limit
0`
============================================================
`root@mako:/proc/sys/kernel # cat core_pattern
cat core_pattern
core`
============================================================
`root@mako:/data/tools/gdb/bin # ulimit -a
ulimit -a
time(cpu-seconds)    unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
coredump(blocks)     0
data(KiB)            unlimited
stack(KiB)           8192
lockedmem(KiB)       65536
nofiles(descriptors) 1024
.......`

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally misread your question and didn't notice the part about you using gdb's gcore command. I looked through gdb's source, and as of version 7.7, it does not honor any core dump size limit when running its gcore command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GameGuardian](http://gameguardian.net/download) for dump memory. Need root. You can dump partially if you need.

Memory editor tab - menu - memory dump - select range and folder - press ok - wait for toast "Dump end".

Here some video examples how to do this:

- [How to dump memory of any running processes in Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/248-how-to-dump-memory-of-any-running-processes-in-android-gameguardian/)
- [How to dump odex file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/251-how-to-dump-odex-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)
- [How to dump deleted file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/252-how-to-dump-deleted-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)